# VS2013 Resharper always runs all tests

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I got this strange problem with VS2013, NUnit and resharper

When I try to run a single test it always runs all tests in the project.  It doesn't matter if  I select Run or Debug or if I start it from the editor, unit test explorer or unit test session.

Only the test I started show up in the Unit Test session. No results from the other tests is visible but break points are hit in all tests.

The problem seem to start at random after editing a test. Have tried clean rebuilds and restarting Visual Studio but the problem remain.

Restarting the computer helps but only until it starts again after some edit.

Using VS2013 update 5, Resharper 10.01 and Nunit 3.0.1 (also tried 2.6.4)

Is this a Visual Studio, NUnit or Resharper problem?

Only other strange thing I noticed is that CTRL-Q (R# show documentation) does not work within test methods. It always show documentation for the test method not the variable or class the cursor is on.

Comment: Do you have your tests sorted by project directory? I reported [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450663) a while back, which appeared 'random', but actually seemed to depend on if the directory had subdirectories or not. Sorting by namespace seems to avoid the problem until it's fixed - haven't had any feedback since reporting it over a month ago however, so don't know when that will be.

Comment: And to address your actual question, I would imagine it to be a resharper problem - if it's not the exact same issue as the one I just mentioned, the symptoms seem far to similar!

Comment: @Chris, thank you for your reply. You are correct about resharper. Installing latest EAP solved the problem for me.

Comment: It also happens in VS2015.